# ¿Cómo hago para que funcione en las subcarpetas?

Tags: python-3.9, extensiones

Tengo una carpeta que tiene documentos, y en esa carpeta hay otra carpeta que tiene otros documentos y así sucesivamente pero, con esta herramienta de Python lo que quiero es poder cambiar las extensiones de determinados archivos, el programa si se ejecuta funciona pero solo lo hace en la 1ª capeta en la segunda no cambia las extensiones.

```py
import time
from colorama import Fore, Style, Back, init
from tqdm import tqdm
import glob
import os

init()
#Funciones

def inicio():
    print('Bienvenido a la herramienta de conversion de archivos de Synology a Microsoft\nEste programa ha sido creado por nuoframework')

def clear():
    if os.name == "nt":
        os.system("cls")
    else:
        os.system("clear")

# Codigo

inicio()

#choose1 = input(f'Inserte la ruta en la que desea que se modifique la extension de los archivos de Synology\n\n'+Fore.RED+'>>> '+Fore.RESET)

choose1 = "C:/Users/viruz/Desktop/DRIVE_MPG/"

clear()

print('\u26A0 · A continuacion se le va a listar todos los archivos con extension'+ Fore.YELLOW +'" .odoc, .osheet"'+ Fore.RESET)

for i in tqdm(range(10)):
    time.sleep(.5)

clear()

print("<--------- · Estos son los archivos encontrados con extansion (.odoc) · --------->")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(choose1):  #Imprime archivos .odoc
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".odoc"):
             print(os.path.join(file))

print("<--------- · Estos son los archivos encontrados con extansion (.osheet) · --------->")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(choose1):  #Imprime archivos .osheet
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".osheet"):
             print(os.path.join(file))

time.sleep(5)

print("\n\n")

print("Se van a cambiar las extensiones de los archivos (.odoc => .docx); (.osheet => .xlsx)")

for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(choose1, '*.odoc')):
    os.rename(filename, filename[:-4] + '.docx')
    print("Se han cambiado las extensiones correctamente")
```

Espero que les sirva, este es el codigo

Comment: PD: lo que cambia las extensiones es el "for" del final de codigo

Comment: haz un `os.listdir()` y luego ve moviendo a las carpetas

Comment: donde lo pongo, como un bucle??? @Christian

Comment: cuales no he definido?

Comment: `os.listdir()` devuelve todo los elementos de un directorio, iteras en esos elementos y luego de haber cambiando todas las extensiones te mueves a alguna carpeta

Comment: @Christian se lo que dices, pero tengo demasiadas subcarpetas no hay otra menera de que cambia los archivos de las subcarpetas ejecutandolo una vez??

Comment: Pueess... que yo sepa nop, de igual forma tendrás que iterar en las sub carpetas, aunque `os.scandir()` te puede resultar más fácil para este caso

Comment: @Christian que variables no he definido???????

Comment: perdón?  No he dicho variables, en un comentario solo dije funciones pero lo eliminé cuando fi que `init()` era importada

Comment: Por casualidad las carpetas están dentro de `DRIVE_MPG` o están dentro de `Desktop`??

Comment: dentro de DRIVE_MPG hay una y dentro de esa hay archivos y otras carpetas y esto se repite por eso decia de cambiar las extensiones que estan dentro de las subcarpetas automaticamente